# Getting distinct only for a certain column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, distinct

I'm trying to select rows with distinct column of 'response', but I'm having trouble doing it. Please take a look at my code:

```
select distinct input,response,
((response REGEXP '[[:<:]]a[[:>:]]')+(response REGEXP '[[:<:]]have[[:>:]]')+(response REGEXP '[[:<:]]I[[:>:]]')) as wordsFound, 
(LENGTH(response) - LENGTH(REPLACE(response, ' ', ''))+1) AS wordsCount 
FROM allData 
HAVING wordsFound > 0 
order by wordsFound desc, wordsCount asc, rand() LIMIT 30
```

If I remove column 'input', in the query, it works, but I also want to select column 'input'. If I put the distinct keyword next to response instead, it'll show an error instead. What should I do to get both the column 'input' and distinct column response?

Comment: select distinct(response), input from....? Or group by response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `DISTINCT` you want to use the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
select input,response,
((response REGEXP '[[:<:]]a[[:>:]]')+(response REGEXP '[[:<:]]have[[:>:]]')+(response REGEXP '[[:<:]]I[[:>:]]')) as wordsFound, 
(LENGTH(response) - LENGTH(REPLACE(response, ' ', ''))+1) AS wordsCount 
FROM allData
GROUP BY response 
HAVING wordsFound > 0 
order by wordsFound desc, wordsCount asc, rand() LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Be aware that if you have to go to a different database with this, it will have to be rewritten as MySQL has fairly...distinctive...implementations of things like this.

Comment: Very true. `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` are also slow. This query tells me there's probably a better way to do it but without seeing his whole schema its hard to make suggestions.

Comment: /agreed  ... with additional characters =P

Comment: That's the whole query.